# Must declare the table variable "@TableName"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting this error in Visual Studio for this part of my code. Why? I do declare `@TableName` below as FormField.

> Must declare the table variable "@TableName".

Code:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
    sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT DisplayName AS MyColumn FROM @TableName WHERE EventId = 1 AND Visible = 1");
    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "FormField";
    sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The table name can not be resolved by using parameter. For this purpose you have to prepare your statement when passing to `SqlCommand`:

```
string tableName = "FormField";

using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
        sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT DisplayName AS MyColumn FROM {0} WHERE EventId = 1 AND Visible = 1", tableName );

        sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

`SqlParameter` can only be used for passing parameter. E.g. in insert or update statements. But if you want to do this, be sure `tableName` can not be changed from outside your source code to prevent from sql injection in any case. Youre maybe able to filter acceptable values before executing any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a table name (or column name or function or operator) as a parameter.

Hence, in your query, `@TableName` is interpreted as a table variable, rather than a parameter and the table variable is not defined.

Alas, you need to put the table in explicitly, using string operations.